How stable is the first harmonic on a vibrating string?
Occasionally, when I play my fiddle, a "forced" harmonic sounds one octave above the fingered note. If I want the note to continue, I can finesse the bow such that the note becomes more resonant and thus more stable. Otherwise, I can immediately apply more force with the bow and "break" the harmonic (returning to the expected pitch). This type of harmonic starts when I play with a gentle bow, and possibly with less finger pressure on the note1. The harmonic in question has just one node impossibly far from my fingers. The effect occurs on electric violins as well, so it's not some quirk of the instrument or the body resonance. Additionally, once the note is sounding, I can increase the volume and see the single node on the vibrating string.
Although I am curious about this phenomenon and whether I can make its occurrence more predictable (as basically asked and inadequately answered here), my main question is about the stability of natural harmonics in general. Given a bowed string with any required variables, how deep is the well for a given harmonic?
1 My right hand maneuvers the bow across the string near the bridge while the left fingers stop the string at appointed places corresponding to notes.
The general advice for regular notes is to depress the string enough that the note rings true (possibly finger to the fingerboard).
Natural harmonics are a touch on the string at a node with virtually no finger pressure.
Between these extremes, we have squeaks, yowls and these, the slightly more predictable 'forced' harmonics.
Artificial harmonics sound when a note is fingered with (often) the index and the string simultaneously touched with the pinky to sound 2 octaves above the fingered note.
EDIT 1:
While I asked this question in the context of forced harmonics, I don't believe any sort of "leaky" barrier analysis is required to answer it (as I suspect it would be for the linked question). Instead, I suspect that higher order effects of general string resonance will give the harmonics an "uncertainty" which will define a well. I can, without question, start a natural harmonic, remove my finger from the node, continue to bow and keep hearing the harmonic for a while. The bow adds energy to the string in a somewhat chaotic way (stick-slip is not a sine-wave oscillator), so that means that the harmonic is stable to small perturbations.
